# JavaFX ChangeListener duration issue

Tags: java, audio, javafx

I'm very new to Java, and after poring over the docs, I'm finding myself stuck.

I have a small program that uses the [JavaFX MediaPlayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html) to play a wav file. My player object has a currentTimeProperty, and I'd like to display the output of this property in minutes:seconds during playback.

So I have this at the end of a function that takes in my wav file and initializes the player:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(wav);
mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new TimeListener());
```

Then I have:

```
public class TimeListener implements ChangeListener {
    public void changed(ObservableValue o, Object oldVal, Object newVal) {

    //Update time display with MediaPlayer's current time:
    currTimeLabel.setText(newVal.toString());
    }
}
```

This works. During playback of the wav, my `currTimeLabel` updates with the current time, in milliseconds. The thing is, I want this time in minutes:seconds.

The variable `newVal` is listed as type "Duration", and the [Duration class](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/util/Duration.html) has methods like `toMinutes()` and `toSeconds()`, but I can't apply them to `newVal`, and I don't understand why.

I can create a new Duration object:

```
Duration testDuration = Duration.millis(100000);
```

And then use the methods:

```
double secondsDuration = testDuration.toSeconds();
// 100.0
```

So if `testDuration` and `newVal` are both duration objects, why can't I apply the methods to `newval`?

And in general, am I on the right track?  I understand there will have to be some string formatting to get my output correct, but it seems to me that first I need to get the value from newVal in a non-string format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your newVal is an Object and not a Duration.  You could cast it and de-reference it like `((Duration)newVal).`  The other better way is to make your method `ChangeListener<Duration>`

```
TimeListener = new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
      @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> o, Duration oldVal, Duration newVal) {
     //now newVal is of Duration class
      }
    };
```